# Не устанавливаются cookie express

Tags: express, cookie, https, axios, backend

Друзья, не могу решить проблему. Искал в интернете, решения не найдены. Жду любых советов.

Бэкенд на Express, хостинг netlify, фронтенд React. Принимаю и отправляю фронтенд запросов через Axios.

Проблема следующая: писал сервер под http, столкнулся с форсированным переходом по протоколу https. На сервере у меня стоит авторизация точь-в-точь (разве что с изменениями лишь в тех местах, где автор использует монго, я изменил код под firebase) как у автора https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fN25fMQZ2v0&ab_channel=UlbiTV. И из-за форсированного перехода на https пришлось переписывать сервер под протокол https, брать сертификат и т.д. Но не в этом суть, это все я сделал. Почему-то, когда отправляю sameSite=none secure cookie, он не проставляется. Но когда логинюсь с пк или андроида - все отлично. Но если я логинюсь через IOS, то уже нет. Просил других людей протестить, у кого-то опять же не устанавливаются куки на пк, у кого-то на мобилке. Из-за чего такое может быть? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Код для куки:

```js
res.cookie('refreshToken', tokens.refreshToken, {maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, httpOnly: true, secure: true, SameSite: 'none', sameSite: 'none'})
```

PS. С пк в основном проблемы в браузере Яндекс, другие браузеры работают +- исправно. В мобилках выборочно работают устройства.

Comment: Какая версия iOS?

Comment: @andreymal IOS 15.6

Comment: Тогда странно, в этой версии теоретически должно работать нормально

Comment: @andreymal Ну да, просто я видимо что-то именно в куках упускаю, ибо у кого-то и с ПК не устанавливается куки. Она как-то выборочно проставляется у всех. Проблемы начались именно после перехода на https и secure куки.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать Same сайты

Comment: @SergeyBogdanets я не могу убрать SameSite, потому что тогда блокируется запрос с сайта

Comment: Корс настройте.

Comment: @SergeyBogdanets не понимаю, что имеете ввиду. Сам запрос проходит, куки блокируется и требует поставить SameSite.